# simplescan --fix-pdf fails with a segmentation fault

Tags: scanning

I'm attempting to use the new `--fix-pdf`
 option of simple scan to fix the errors in pdf files created by earlier versions of simple scan.

The command:

```
simple-scan --fix-pdf test.pdf
```

results in a segmentation fault.
Has anyone successfully used the `--fix-pdf` option?

Comment: Could be that it can't handle that broken PDF (regardless previous version). I had similar errors with bad PDFs using GhostScript

Answer (score 1):

Broken PDFs in Simple Scan

Since version 2.32 **Simple Scan has had a bug** where it generates PDF files with invalid cross-reference tables.

The good news is this bug is now fixed, and will work correctly in simple-scan 3.2; thanks to Rafał Mużyło who diagnosed this.

You may not have noticed this bug as a number of PDF readers handle these types of failures and rebuild the table (e.g. Evince).  It was noticed that some versions of Adobe Reader do not handle these failures.

[this is the fix](http://bobthegnome.blogspot.com/2011/09/broken-pdfs-in-simple-scan.html)